# Making a div change size with animate, addClass and RemoveClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

This is my first question here, feel free to tell me if I am not specific enough or whatever I do wrong!
I want a jquery method which change all divs with the class "passive" to height 500 px and passive-->active, so there would be another method which changes the height back to 100px. The first half is working, I got the class changed, but the second animation won't happen. All I have in html is one div with the class of passive.

```
$("document").ready(function(){

$(function() { 

$(".passive").click(function(){
$(this).animate({height:'500px'});
$(this).addClass("active");
$(this).removeClass("passive");    
});    


$(".active").click(function(){
$(this).animate({height:'100px'});
$(this).addClass("passive");
$(this).removeClass("active");
});   

});
});`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jQuery.animate()` is costly and choppy. You will get a smoother transition by just toggling the class and using CSS to transition

```
.passive {  
  height:100px; 
  transition:height 1s;
}
.active { 
  height:300px;
}
```

```js
Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('.passive'))
  .forEach(
    e => e.addEventListener(
           'click', 
           evnt => e.classList.toggle('active')  
    )
)
```

```css
.container { display:flex; }
.container>div { 
  flex:1 auto;
}

.passive { 
  background-color:red; 
  margin:5px; 
  height:100px; 
  width:20px; 
  transition:height 1s;
}
.active { 
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="passive" tabindex=1></div>
  <div class="passive" tabindex=2></div>
  <div class="passive" tabindex=3></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to interact with a class added after the DOM loaded. By default, click functions will only work with elements that exist on load. You can either use event delegation or add a base class to the element. If you add a base class, you can simplify the click function.

You can do an if/else to check if the element has a certain class using `hasClass`. Also, you can chain together the `$(this)` methods inside the if/else blocks.

```
$("document").ready(function() {

    $(function() {


        $("baseclassname").click(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass('passive')) {
                $(this).animate({ height: '500px' });
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(this).removeClass("passive");
            // $(this).animate({ height: '500px' }).addClass('active').removeClass('passive');
            } else {
                $(this).animate({ height: '100px' });
                $(this).addClass("passive");
                $(this).removeClass("active");
                // $(this).animate({ height: '100px' }).addClass('passive').removeClass('active');
            }
        });
    });

});
```